# Wordpress- creating custom post and give user access to edit only this post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a case.

I have a custom post type which is defined as:

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_galerie_absolwentow');
function my_custom_galerie_absolwentow() 
{
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Galerie absolwentów', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Galeria absolwentów', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Dodaj nową galerię', 'Blog'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Dodaj nową'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edycja'),
    'new_item' => __('Nowa'),
    'view_item' => __('Zobacz'),
    'search_items' => __('Szukaj'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nie znaleziono żadnych galerii'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nie znaleziono żadnych galerii w koszu'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'has_archive' => 'galerie-absolwentow'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'galerie-absolwentow',
            'with_front' => false
            ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 15,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes'),
    'has_archive' => 'galerie-absolwentow'

  ); 
  register_post_type('galerie-absolwentow',$args);
}
```

I'm creating new post with status 'draft' when creating user with specifed role.

```
add_action ('user_register', "add_post_to_absolwent_user");
function add_post_to_absolwent_user($user_id)
{

    if ($_POST['role']=='absolwent'):
         $absolwent_page = array(
            'post_title' => __($_POST['first_name'].' '.$_POST['last_name']),
            'post_content' => 'Tutaj należy wprowadzić krótki opis strony Absolwenta.',
            'post_type' => 'galerie-absolwentow',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        );

        $absolwent_page_id = wp_insert_post($absolwent_page);


    endif;

}
```

This code is ok, and do what I want to do :)

What I need to do to give an access for created user to created post.
That's all.
Everything else should not be accessible.

Is this possible ? 
Any hints how to achieve this?